# Shapefile of South Tyneside borough (north-east England) boundary

Tags: shapefile, polygon, download, data

I'm looking for a free-to-download shapefile (polygons) of South Tyneside borough. [South Tyneside](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=south%20tyneside%20borough&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) is a metropolitan borough in NE England. Can anyone help?

Comment: OS Boundaryline is part of the open data set

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be a suitable place to research/ask this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use free and open [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) data.

With the Overpass-API it's possible to download the data.
Simply [follow this link to run the query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/fdu), click "export" and choose your prefered format (e.g. GeoJSON).
Alternatively, run a query by typing `name="South Tyneside"` and execute the query.